# Extending plot function

Tags: pine-script

Afternoon all,

I am currently using the below to plot a line (using yesterdays data), plotting on today chart (only currently plots for 24 hours).
What I would like to do is to have it continuously extend to the right.

Is this possible?

```
plot(pastLine, "Past Line", change(pastLine) ? na : color.purple, offset = 0)
```

[image]

@Bjorn thank you for your reply
Extend is indeed wrong and it is track price I am after but for the previous plotted lines.

Thank you for your time
Daniel

##Updated 31/01/2021 @ 1800 - As per Bjorn request##

Please see script I am using below. I would like to extend all previous purple lines to the price track.

```
    //@version=4
study(title="Points of Interest", shorttitle="Points of Interest", overlay=true)

//Session Rules
bartimeSess = time('D')
newbarSess = bartimeSess != bartimeSess[1]
offset_val = input(title="Label Offset", type=input.integer, defval=6)

va_percent = input(0.7, title = "Value Area", type = input.float, 
     minval = 0.1, maxval = 1, step = 0.1)
     

dtf = input("D", title = "Time Frame", type = input.resolution)
resolution = input(1, title = "Resolution", type = input.float)

is_new_bar(t) => 
    change(time(t)) != 0

round_to_nearest(v, x) => 
    round(v / x) * x


tick_size = max(syminfo.mintick, resolution)

var a = array.new_float(0)

a_min = 0.0, a_min := nz(a_min[1], round_to_nearest(low, tick_size))
a_max = 0.0, a_max := nz(a_max[1], round_to_nearest(high, tick_size))

d_switch = is_new_bar(dtf)

if d_switch
    a_min := low
    a_max := high
    array.clear(a)

// Scaled min max
v_min = int(round_to_nearest(low - a_min, tick_size) / tick_size)
v_max = int(round_to_nearest(high - a_min, tick_size) / tick_size)

// Scaled candle range
ticks = v_max - v_min

vol = volume / (ticks == 0 ? 1 : ticks)

for i = v_min to max(v_max - 1, v_min)
    
    // Insert new low value
    if i < 0
        array.insert(a, i - v_min, vol)
        continue
    
    // Adjust index
    offset = v_min < 0 ? abs(v_min) : 0
    index = int(i + offset)
    
    // Push new high value
    if index >= array.size(a)
        array.push(a, vol)
        continue
    
    // Update existing value
    v = array.get(a, index)
    array.set(a, index, v + vol)

// Array bounds
a_min := min(a_min, round_to_nearest(low, tick_size))
a_max := max(a_max, round_to_nearest(high, tick_size))
a_size = array.size(a)

// { POC

poc_index = -1
poc_prev = -1.0
sum_vol = 0.0

for i = 0 to a_size - 1
    
    poc_current = array.get(a, i)
    sum_vol := sum_vol + poc_current
    
    if poc_current > poc_prev
        poc_prev := poc_current
        poc_index := i

// }

// { VA

va_high_index = poc_index
va_low_index  = poc_index
    
va_vol_cap = sum_vol * va_percent
sum_va_vol = array.get(a, poc_index)

for i = 1 to a_size - 1
    
    above = 0.0
    if va_high_index + 1 < a_size - 1
        above := above + nz(array.get(a, (va_high_index + 1)), 0.0)
    if va_high_index + 2 < a_size - 1
        above := above + nz(array.get(a, (va_high_index + 2)), 0.0)
        
    below = 0.0
    if va_low_index - 1 > 0
        below := below + nz(array.get(a, (va_low_index - 1)), 0.0)
    if va_low_index - 2 > 0
        below := below + nz(array.get(a, (va_low_index - 2)), 0.0)
    
    if above > below
        va_high_index := min(va_high_index + 2, a_size - 1)
        sum_va_vol  := sum_va_vol + above
    else
        va_low_index := max(va_low_index - 2, 0)
        sum_va_vol := sum_va_vol + below
        
    if sum_va_vol >= va_vol_cap or (va_low_index <= 0 and va_high_index >= a_size - 1)
        break

// }

float p_poc = 0.0

float d_poc = 0.0
float b_poc = 0.0


d_poc  := poc_index * tick_size + a_min

if is_new_bar(dtf)
    p_poc  := d_poc[1]

else
    p_poc  := p_poc[1]


plot(p_poc, " pd_POC", change(p_poc) ? na : color.purple, offset = 0, trackprice=true)

plotshape(p_poc, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.purple,  textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="pdPOC",  offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="pdPOC")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot extend a `plot`. You could try to use the `trackprice` parameter for that purpose.

```
plot(pastLine, "Past Line", change(pastLine) ? na : color.purple, offset = 0, trackprice=true)
```

Update 31/01/2021: Using lines instead of plot.

```
//@version=4
study(title="Points of Interest", shorttitle="Points of Interest", overlay=true, max_lines_count=500)

//Session Rules
bartimeSess = time('D')
newbarSess = bartimeSess != bartimeSess[1]
offset_val = input(title="Label Offset", type=input.integer, defval=6)

va_percent = input(0.7, title = "Value Area", type = input.float, 
     minval = 0.1, maxval = 1, step = 0.1)
     

dtf = input("D", title = "Time Frame", type = input.resolution)
resolution = input(1, title = "Resolution", type = input.float)

is_new_bar(t) => change(time(t)) != 0
round_to_nearest(v, x) => round(v / x) * x

tick_size = max(syminfo.mintick, resolution)

var a = array.new_float(0)

a_min = 0.0, a_min := nz(a_min[1], round_to_nearest(low, tick_size))
a_max = 0.0, a_max := nz(a_max[1], round_to_nearest(high, tick_size))

d_switch = is_new_bar(dtf)

if d_switch
    a_min := low
    a_max := high
    array.clear(a)

// Scaled min max
v_min = int(round_to_nearest(low - a_min, tick_size) / tick_size)
v_max = int(round_to_nearest(high - a_min, tick_size) / tick_size)

// Scaled candle range
ticks = v_max - v_min

vol = volume / (ticks == 0 ? 1 : ticks)

for i = v_min to max(v_max - 1, v_min)
    // Insert new low value
    if i < 0
        array.insert(a, i - v_min, vol)
        continue
    
    // Adjust index
    offset = v_min < 0 ? abs(v_min) : 0
    index = int(i + offset)
    
    // Push new high value
    if index >= array.size(a)
        array.push(a, vol)
        continue
    
    // Update existing value
    v = array.get(a, index)
    array.set(a, index, v + vol)

// Array bounds
a_min := min(a_min, round_to_nearest(low, tick_size))
a_max := max(a_max, round_to_nearest(high, tick_size))
a_size = array.size(a)

// { POC

poc_index = -1
poc_prev = -1.0
sum_vol = 0.0

for i = 0 to a_size - 1
    poc_current = array.get(a, i)
    sum_vol := sum_vol + poc_current
    
    if poc_current > poc_prev
        poc_prev := poc_current
        poc_index := i

// }

// { VA

va_high_index = poc_index
va_low_index  = poc_index
    
va_vol_cap = sum_vol * va_percent
sum_va_vol = array.get(a, poc_index)

for i = 1 to a_size - 1
    
    above = 0.0
    if va_high_index + 1 < a_size - 1
        above := above + nz(array.get(a, (va_high_index + 1)), 0.0)
    if va_high_index + 2 < a_size - 1
        above := above + nz(array.get(a, (va_high_index + 2)), 0.0)
        
    below = 0.0
    if va_low_index - 1 > 0
        below := below + nz(array.get(a, (va_low_index - 1)), 0.0)
    if va_low_index - 2 > 0
        below := below + nz(array.get(a, (va_low_index - 2)), 0.0)
    
    if above > below
        va_high_index := min(va_high_index + 2, a_size - 1)
        sum_va_vol  := sum_va_vol + above
    else
        va_low_index := max(va_low_index - 2, 0)
        sum_va_vol := sum_va_vol + below
        
    if sum_va_vol >= va_vol_cap or (va_low_index <= 0 and va_high_index >= a_size - 1)
        break

// }

float p_poc = 0.0
float d_poc = 0.0
float b_poc = 0.0

d_poc  := poc_index * tick_size + a_min

// if is_new_bar(dtf)
//     p_poc  := d_poc[1]
// else
//     p_poc  := p_poc[1]

p_poc := is_new_bar(dtf) ? d_poc[1] : p_poc[1]

if is_new_bar(dtf)
    line.new(time, p_poc, time+1, p_poc, xloc=xloc.bar_time, color=color.purple, extend=extend.right)

// plot(p_poc, " pd_POC", change(p_poc) ? na : color.purple, offset = 0, trackprice=true)

plotshape(p_poc, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.purple,  textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="pdPOC",  offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="pdPOC")
```

Yields this (max 500 lines)
[image]

**Edit 1** in response to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65981358/extending-plot-function/65981462?noredirect=1#comment117901832_65981462)
Keep non-broken poc's

```
//@version=4
study(title="Points of Interest", shorttitle="Points of Interest", overlay=true, max_lines_count=500)

//Session Rules
bartimeSess = time('D')
newbarSess = bartimeSess != bartimeSess[1]
offset_val = input(title="Label Offset", type=input.integer, defval=6)

va_percent = input(0.7, title = "Value Area", type = input.float, 
     minval = 0.1, maxval = 1, step = 0.1)
     

dtf = input("D", title = "Time Frame", type = input.resolution)
resolution = input(1, title = "Resolution", type = input.float)

is_new_bar(t) => change(time(t)) != 0
round_to_nearest(v, x) => round(v / x) * x

tick_size = max(syminfo.mintick, resolution)

var a = array.new_float(0)

a_min = 0.0, a_min := nz(a_min[1], round_to_nearest(low, tick_size))
a_max = 0.0, a_max := nz(a_max[1], round_to_nearest(high, tick_size))

d_switch = is_new_bar(dtf)

if d_switch
    a_min := low
    a_max := high
    array.clear(a)

// Scaled min max
v_min = int(round_to_nearest(low - a_min, tick_size) / tick_size)
v_max = int(round_to_nearest(high - a_min, tick_size) / tick_size)

// Scaled candle range
ticks = v_max - v_min

vol = volume / (ticks == 0 ? 1 : ticks)

for i = v_min to max(v_max - 1, v_min)
    // Insert new low value
    if i < 0
        array.insert(a, i - v_min, vol)
        continue
    
    // Adjust index
    offset = v_min < 0 ? abs(v_min) : 0
    index = int(i + offset)
    
    // Push new high value
    if index >= array.size(a)
        array.push(a, vol)
        continue
    
    // Update existing value
    v = array.get(a, index)
    array.set(a, index, v + vol)

// Array bounds
a_min := min(a_min, round_to_nearest(low, tick_size))
a_max := max(a_max, round_to_nearest(high, tick_size))
a_size = array.size(a)

// { POC

poc_index = -1
poc_prev = -1.0
sum_vol = 0.0

for i = 0 to a_size - 1
    poc_current = array.get(a, i)
    sum_vol := sum_vol + poc_current
    
    if poc_current > poc_prev
        poc_prev := poc_current
        poc_index := i

// }

// { VA

va_high_index = poc_index
va_low_index  = poc_index
    
va_vol_cap = sum_vol * va_percent
sum_va_vol = array.get(a, poc_index)

for i = 1 to a_size - 1
    
    above = 0.0
    if va_high_index + 1 < a_size - 1
        above := above + nz(array.get(a, (va_high_index + 1)), 0.0)
    if va_high_index + 2 < a_size - 1
        above := above + nz(array.get(a, (va_high_index + 2)), 0.0)
        
    below = 0.0
    if va_low_index - 1 > 0
        below := below + nz(array.get(a, (va_low_index - 1)), 0.0)
    if va_low_index - 2 > 0
        below := below + nz(array.get(a, (va_low_index - 2)), 0.0)
    
    if above > below
        va_high_index := min(va_high_index + 2, a_size - 1)
        sum_va_vol  := sum_va_vol + above
    else
        va_low_index := max(va_low_index - 2, 0)
        sum_va_vol := sum_va_vol + below
        
    if sum_va_vol >= va_vol_cap or (va_low_index <= 0 and va_high_index >= a_size - 1)
        break

// }

float p_poc = 0.0
float d_poc = 0.0
float b_poc = 0.0

d_poc  := poc_index * tick_size + a_min

// if is_new_bar(dtf)
//     p_poc  := d_poc[1]
// else
//     p_poc  := p_poc[1]

p_poc := is_new_bar(dtf) ? d_poc[1] : p_poc[1]

var line[]  lines = array.new_line()
var float[] pocs  = array.new_float()

if is_new_bar(dtf)
    array.push(lines, line.new(time, p_poc, time+1, p_poc, xloc=xloc.bar_time, color=color.purple, extend=extend.right))
    array.push(pocs, p_poc)

if array.size(pocs) > 0
    for i = 0 to array.size(pocs)-1
        mypoc = array.get(pocs,i)
        if mypoc > low
            line.delete(array.get(lines,i))

// plot(p_poc, " pd_POC", change(p_poc) ? na : color.purple, offset = 0, trackprice=true)

plotshape(p_poc, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.purple,  textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="pdPOC",  offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="pdPOC")
```

Comment: I have updated my submission. I am after the previous lines to track price. I added the trackprice but it only does it for the current purple line. Is there a way to do it for the previous purple lines?

Comment: No, trackprice will only track the last price. But if I understand correctly, you want all purple lines to extend to the right? If yes, you'd be better off using lines for that purpose. Please update your question with the entire script. I'll have a look.

Comment: updated with script. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you sure you want ALL those purple lines to extend right? You won't be able to tell them apart because there'll be so many.

Comment: I am then hoping to use the information along with other information with if statements for them to only show as points of confluence when 2 or 3 are true. Does that make sense.

Comment: Amazing Bjorn I am going to read through to understand the changes. Thank you

Comment: Bjorn, apologies for posting another comment on a closed question. But I was wondering if there is a way to code to only show the lines where price hasn't crossed over. Thinking in my head so it only captures the virgin/naked POCs.

Comment: Added Edit 1 to my answer.

Comment: Absolutely amazing. Thank you for your time. You make it look easy :-).

Comment: Bjorn Mistiaen, I hope you are well. I have a similar question to this that you might be able to help me with reference the Non Broken element. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68142913/when-30-minute-candle-closes-create-line-new-every-50-high-and-low

Comment: I hope you are well. I have been rattling my brain trying to put an alert condition on the non-broken lines. So when price crosses a non-broken an alert goes off. But everything I have tried has not work. Any advice would be gratefully received.