# When 30 minute candle closes, create line.new every $50 high and low

Tags: pine-script

Afternoon all,

Is there a way to create line.new once a 30 minute candle has closed for every $50's of that candle.

Then when price passes back through those lines are then deleted and not recreated?

I am trying to get it to highlight single prints, where price within a 24 hour period has not been retraced after a 30 min candle.

I think the non-broken element within this question might work.
[Extending plot function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65981358/extending-plot-function/65981462?noredirect=1#comment116661035_65981462)

Below is an example
[image]

```
//@version=4
study("Single Print", shorttitle="SP", overlay=true)
//30 min chart
Incr = input(50, "Increment(50)")

Date = input(title="Date", type=input.time, defval=timestamp("27 Jun 2021 00:00"))


Top = 0.0, Bot = 0.0
Top := time == Date? high : Top[1]
Bot := time == Date? low  : Bot[1]

if time > Date
    Top := high > Top[1]? high : Top[1]
    Bot := low  < Bot[1]? low  : Bot[1]

rTop = ceil(Top/Incr) * Incr
rBot = floor(Bot/Incr) * Incr


NoLines = (rTop - rBot) / Incr
//array
a_lines = array.new_float(NoLines)
for x = 0 to NoLines -1
    array.set(a_lines, x, rBot + (x * Incr))

a_used = array.new_bool(NoLines)
for x = 0 to NoLines -1
    break
    //Determine if line was already used


Get_Array(ArrayName,index) => value = array.get(ArrayName,index)

for i = 0 to NoLines - 1
    Y = Get_Array(a_lines,i)
    U = Get_Array(a_used,i)
    theline = line.new(x1 = Date, y1 = Y, x2 = timenow, y2 = Y, 
      color=color.new(color.red, 70), width=3, extend=extend.none, xloc=xloc.bar_time)
    if U
        line.delete(theline)
```

##################UPDATE to Question 28/06/2021#########

Bjorn amazing as always.

I have a second question which I am not sure if it is achievable.

1. Is there a way to get the intervals to whole $50 (maybe rounding the high/lo).
2. When a line is created and price passes back through that line is deleted, is there a way for when the new price action line is created (after that deletion) it looks back and says if we are deleting a line do not create a new line.

This would leave only the areas that have not been retraced by price action. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Bjorn Mistiaen hope you are well. Would you be able to assist with this question I think it is similar to this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65981358/extending-plot-function/65981462?noredirect=1#comment116661035_65981462

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
//@version=4

var int     max_lines = 500

study("Lines", max_lines_count=max_lines, overlay=true)

i_line_distance = input(50,        "Distance between lines",            input.float)
i_max_array     = input(max_lines, "Max array size",                    input.integer, minval=max_lines, maxval=100000)
i_include_high  = input(true,      "Draw line at high",                 input.bool)
i_remove_gaps   = input(true,      "Remove line if price gaps over it", input.bool)

var line[]  a_lines     = array.new_line()
var float   last_level  = na
var int     size_array  = na

f_add_line(_level) =>
    if array.size(a_lines) >= i_max_array
        line.delete(array.shift(a_lines))
    array.push(a_lines, line.new(bar_index-1, _level, bar_index, _level, extend=extend.right))
    _level

// Create new lines
if barstate.isconfirmed[1]
    lo = low[1], hi = high[1]

    for level = lo to hi by i_line_distance
        last_level := f_add_line(level)

    if i_include_high and last_level != hi
        f_add_line(hi)

// Delete touched lines
a_idx_deleted = array.new_int()
size_array := array.size(a_lines)
if size_array > 0
    for i = 0 to size_array - 1
        p = line.get_price(array.get(a_lines, i), bar_index)
        if (p >= low and p <= high) or (i_remove_gaps and ((p >= high[1] and p <= high) or (p <= low[1] and p >= low)))
            line.delete(array.get(a_lines, i))
            array.push(a_idx_deleted, i) // Remember which line was deleted (for cleanup of lines array)

// Remove deleted lines from lines array
array.reverse(a_idx_deleted)
size_array := array.size(a_idx_deleted)
if size_array > 0
    for i = 0 to size_array - 1
        array.remove(a_lines, array.get(a_idx_deleted, i))
```

**Edit 1** in response to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68142913/when-30-minute-candle-closes-create-line-new-every-50-high-and-low/68154167?noredirect=1#comment120477356_68154167)

```
//@version=4

var int     max_lines = 500

study("Lines", max_lines_count=max_lines, overlay=true)

i_line_distance = input(50,        "Distance between lines",            input.float)
i_max_array     = input(max_lines, "Max array size",                    input.integer, minval=max_lines, maxval=100000)
i_remove_gaps   = input(true,      "Remove line if price gaps over it", input.bool)

var line[]  a_lines             = array.new_line()
var float[] a_levels_deleted    = array.new_float()
var float   last_level          = na
var int     size_array          = na

f_add_line(_level) =>
    if not array.includes(a_levels_deleted, _level) // Don't redraw deleted lines
        if array.size(a_lines) >= i_max_array
            line.delete(array.shift(a_lines))
        array.push(a_lines, line.new(bar_index-1, _level, bar_index, _level, extend=extend.right))

// Create new lines
if barstate.isconfirmed[1]
    // Round to interval
    lo = ceil(low[1] / i_line_distance) * i_line_distance
    hi = floor(high[1] / i_line_distance) * i_line_distance

    for level = lo to hi by i_line_distance
        f_add_line(level)


// Delete touched lines
a_idx_deleted = array.new_int()
size_array := array.size(a_lines)
if size_array > 0
    for i = 0 to size_array - 1
        p = line.get_price(array.get(a_lines, i), bar_index)
        if (p >= low and p <= high) or (i_remove_gaps and ((p >= high[1] and p <= high) or (p <= low[1] and p >= low)))
            line.delete(array.get(a_lines, i))
            array.push(a_idx_deleted, i) // Remember which line was deleted (for cleanup of lines array)
            array.push(a_levels_deleted, p)

// Remove deleted lines from lines array
array.reverse(a_idx_deleted)
size_array := array.size(a_idx_deleted)
if size_array > 0
    for i = 0 to size_array - 1
        array.remove(a_lines, array.get(a_idx_deleted, i))
```

**Edit 2** in response to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68142913/when-30-minute-candle-closes-create-line-new-every-50-high-and-low/68154167?noredirect=1#comment120479914_68154167)

```
//@version=4

var int     max_lines = 500

study("Lines", max_lines_count=max_lines, overlay=true)

i_line_distance = input(50,                         "Distance between lines",            input.float)
i_max_array     = input(max_lines,                  "Max array size",                    input.integer, minval=max_lines, maxval=100000)
i_remove_gaps   = input(true,                       "Remove line if price gaps over it", input.bool)

var line[]  a_lines             = array.new_line()
var float[] a_levels_deleted    = array.new_float()
var int     size_array          = na

f_add_line(_level) =>
    if not array.includes(a_levels_deleted, _level) // Don't redraw deleted lines
        if array.size(a_lines) >= i_max_array
            line.delete(array.shift(a_lines))
        array.push(a_lines, line.new(bar_index-1, _level, bar_index, _level, extend=extend.right))

// Only plot last 24h
if change(dayofweek)
    size_array := array.size(a_lines)
    if size_array > 0
        for i = 0 to size_array - 1
            line.delete(array.get(a_lines, i))
    array.clear(a_lines)
    array.clear(a_levels_deleted)

// Create new lines
if barstate.isconfirmed[1]
    // Round to interval
    lo = ceil(low[1] / i_line_distance) * i_line_distance
    hi = floor(high[1] / i_line_distance) * i_line_distance

    for level = lo to hi by i_line_distance
        f_add_line(level)


// Delete touched lines
a_idx_deleted = array.new_int()
size_array := array.size(a_lines)
if size_array > 0
    for i = 0 to size_array - 1
        p = line.get_price(array.get(a_lines, i), bar_index)
        if (p >= low and p <= high) or (i_remove_gaps and ((p >= high[1] and p <= high) or (p <= low[1] and p >= low)))
            line.delete(array.get(a_lines, i))
            array.push(a_idx_deleted, i) // Remember which line was deleted (for cleanup of lines array)
            array.push(a_levels_deleted, p)


// Remove deleted lines from lines array
array.reverse(a_idx_deleted)
size_array := array.size(a_idx_deleted)
if size_array > 0
    for i = 0 to size_array - 1
        array.remove(a_lines, array.get(a_idx_deleted, i))
```

**Edit 3** Keep untouched lines for each day

```
//@version=4

var int     max_lines = 500

study("Lines", max_lines_count=max_lines, overlay=true)

i_line_distance = input(50,                         "Distance between lines",            input.float)
i_max_array     = input(max_lines,                  "Max array size",                    input.integer, minval=max_lines, maxval=100000)
i_remove_gaps   = input(true,                       "Remove line if price gaps over it", input.bool)

var line[]  a_lines             = array.new_line()
var float[] a_levels_deleted    = array.new_float()
var int     size_array          = na

f_add_line(_level) =>
    if not array.includes(a_levels_deleted, _level) // Don't redraw deleted lines
        if array.size(a_lines) >= i_max_array
            line.delete(array.shift(a_lines))
        array.push(a_lines, line.new(bar_index-1, _level, bar_index, _level, extend=extend.right))

// Keep untouched lines for each day
if change(dayofweek)
    // change length of existing lines
    size_array := array.size(a_lines)
    if size_array > 0
        for i = 0 to size_array - 1
            myLine = array.get(a_lines, i)
            line.set_x2(myLine, bar_index)
            line.set_extend(myLine, extend.none)
    array.clear(a_lines)
    array.clear(a_levels_deleted)

// Create new lines
if barstate.isconfirmed[1]
    // Round to interval
    lo = ceil(low[1] / i_line_distance) * i_line_distance
    hi = floor(high[1] / i_line_distance) * i_line_distance

    for level = lo to hi by i_line_distance
        f_add_line(level)


// Delete touched lines
a_idx_deleted = array.new_int()
size_array := array.size(a_lines)
if size_array > 0
    for i = 0 to size_array - 1
        p = line.get_price(array.get(a_lines, i), bar_index)
        if (p >= low and p <= high) or (i_remove_gaps and ((p >= high[1] and p <= high) or (p <= low[1] and p >= low)))
            line.delete(array.get(a_lines, i))
            array.push(a_idx_deleted, i) // Remember which line was deleted (for cleanup of lines array)
            array.push(a_levels_deleted, p)


// Remove deleted lines from lines array
array.reverse(a_idx_deleted)
size_array := array.size(a_idx_deleted)
if size_array > 0
    for i = 0 to size_array - 1
        array.remove(a_lines, array.get(a_idx_deleted, i))
```

Comment: Bjorn amazing as always.
I have a second question which I am not sure if it is achievable. 
1. Is there a way to get the intervals to whole $50 (maybe rounding the high/lo).
2. When a line is created and price passes back through that line is deleted, is there a way for when the new price action line is created (after that deletion) it looks back and says if we are deleting a line do not create a new line. This would leave only the areas that have not been retraced by price action. Does that make sense?

Comment: For your point 1. I don't understand. Can you give an example with numbers pls?

Comment: So say a candle high is 34618 (BTCUSDT) that this would be rounded down to 34600 or if a low was 34540 it would be round to up 34550.

Comment: Both issues solved. Added Edit 1 section to my answer.

Comment: Bjorn thank you I have marked the question as answered.
One final question.
Looking at the output of edit one is there a way to section this so it produces this within a daily period. So that I could see single prints for each daily period isolated? 
Does that make sense?

Comment: If the daily isolation is not possible would a configured look back start date be configurable? Or start and finish date?

Comment: Added Edit 2 section to my answer, which will only plot the last 24 hours (current session actually, instead of 24 hours).

Comment: Yes, but I'd prefer to keep discussions on SO. That way the entire community benefits from the shared knowledge.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234317/discussion-between-frien-dd-and-bjorn-mistiaen).