# extending pivot high and low lines in pine script

Tags: pine-script

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='s/r', shorttitle='s/r', overlay=true, max_bars_back=1000)


leftBars = input(10, title='Left Bars ')

rightBars = input(10, title='Right Bars')

volumeThresh = input(20, title='Volume Threshold')

highUsePivot = fixnan(ta.pivothigh(leftBars, rightBars)[1]) 

lowUsePivot = fixnan(ta.pivotlow(leftBars, rightBars)[1])

r1 = plot(highUsePivot, color=ta.change(highUsePivot) ? na : color.green, linewidth=1, offset=-(rightBars + 1), title='Resistance')

s1 = plot(lowUsePivot, color=ta.change(lowUsePivot) ? na : color.green, linewidth=1, offset=-(rightBars + 1), title='Support')
```

..................................................

This code draws pivot high and low support and resistance.
[image]

How can I extend these lines to the right?

Thank you

....................

Comment: May be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65981358/extending-plot-function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the script below.
The plot cannot be extended, you have to use `line` objects and a `var` array to store them.

```
//@version=5 
indicator(title='s/r', shorttitle='s/r', overlay=true, max_bars_back=1000)

leftBars = input(10, title='Left Bars ')
rightBars = input(10, title='Right Bars')

volumeThresh = input(20, title='Volume Threshold')
highUsePivot = fixnan(ta.pivothigh(leftBars, rightBars)[1])
lowUsePivot = fixnan(ta.pivotlow(leftBars, rightBars)[1])


var arPivotHighs = array.new<line>()
var arPivotLows = array.new<line>()
maxPivots = input.int(5, "How many last pivots to draw")

ph = ta.pivothigh(leftBars, rightBars)
pl = ta.pivotlow(leftBars, rightBars)

if ph
    ln = line.new(bar_index-rightBars, ph, bar_index, ph, extend = extend.right, color = color.red, width = 2)
    arPivotHighs.unshift(ln)
    while arPivotHighs.size() > maxPivots
        arPivotHighs.last().delete()
        arPivotHighs.pop()

if pl
    ln = line.new(bar_index-rightBars, pl, bar_index, pl, extend = extend.right, color = color.green, width = 2)
    arPivotLows.unshift(ln)
    while arPivotLows.size() > maxPivots
        arPivotLows.last().delete()
        arPivotLows.pop()


// r1 = plot(highUsePivot, color=ta.change(highUsePivot) ? na : color.green, linewidth=1, offset=-(rightBars + 1), title='Resistance')
// s1 = plot(lowUsePivot, color=ta.change(lowUsePivot) ? na : color.green, linewidth=1, offset=-(rightBars + 1), title='Support')
```

The script below draws 4H pivots:

```
//@version=5 
indicator(title='s/r', shorttitle='s/r', overlay=true, max_bars_back=1000)

leftBars = input(10, title='Left Bars ')
rightBars = input(10, title='Right Bars')

Tf1 = input.timeframe("240", "Higher timeframe") 

[h, l, ph, pl, t1, t2, bi] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, Tf1, [
                                                          high
                                                          , low
                                                          , ta.pivothigh(high, leftBars, rightBars)
                                                          , ta.pivotlow(low, leftBars, rightBars)
                                                          , time[math.min(bar_index, leftBars+rightBars+1)]
                                                          , time_close[1]
                                                          , bar_index
                                                          ])


newHTFBar = ta.change(bi) // detect when data for new HTF bar becomes first available

var arPivotHighs = array.new<line>()
var arPivotLows = array.new<line>()
maxPivots = input.int(5, "How many last pivots to draw")


// we only draw lines on the first chart TF's bar of each HTF bar
if ph and newHTFBar
    ln = line.new(t1, ph, t2, ph, extend = extend.none, color = color.red, width = 2, xloc = xloc.bar_time)
    arPivotHighs.unshift(ln)
    while arPivotHighs.size() > maxPivots
        arPivotHighs.last().delete()
        arPivotHighs.pop()

if pl and newHTFBar
    ln = line.new(t1, pl, t2, pl, extend = extend.none, color = color.green, width = 2, xloc = xloc.bar_time)
    arPivotLows.unshift(ln)
    while arPivotLows.size() > maxPivots
        arPivotLows.last().delete()
        arPivotLows.pop()
```

Comment: It worked! After that I tried adding (timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true) in the indicator function to make it MTF, but I got this error "The 'timeframe' argument is incompatible with functions that have side effects". would you be kind to look at this as well? thank you

Comment: Please see the supplemented answer